# Unable to pass date value to controller method via jquery post method.

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, date, jquery-post

I have a json object like this :

```
var data = {}; 
data = 
 { "First" : _this.getFirstElement.val(), 
    "Second": _this.getSecondElement.val(),
    "DateProperty" : _this.getDatePropertyElement.val()
 };
```

This is passed to the controller method using jquery post :

```
$.post(url,data,function(){somefunction});
```

My controller method is like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public void ControllerMethod(TestObject data)
{
    // data.DateProperty is coming as null
   // logic 
}
```

What did i miss?

The FormData passed when looked in the network section of browser specifies data as :

```
      FormData : 
      First : <some data>
      Second : <some data>
      DateProperty : some long date string
```

Later i changed json data to send date as 
      JSON.stringify()

Now in the formData , value is coming as

```
    First : <some data>
    Second : <some data>
    DateProperty : "05/06/16"
```

But still at Controller method, dateProperty is null ?

Comment: What you've described should work fine. Are you sure that the property name for `DateProperty` match whats defined in the C# model?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - yes. The property is same at C# side.

Comment: I had a weird observation - when i hardcode the value of post data from the browser and set the dateProperty as "09/07/10". It gave correct date value at controller.

Comment: using dateFormat in jquery for the date value worked for me.  Got Idea from : http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the date value from javascript using dateFormat resolved the issue.

This is how I formatted the date value :

```
var data = {}; 
data = {
    "First" : _this.getFirstElement.val(), 
    "Second": _this.getSecondElement.val(),
    "DateProperty" : dateFormat(_this.getDatePropertyElement.val(), "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss"),
};
```

With this date value is received at the controller method.

References : 
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format